# angular ng-table does not sort

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ngtable

I am having trouble sorting ng-table. I am not sure what's wrong here. Nothing happens when I click on a header.

I have this controller

```
'use strict';

import $ from 'jquery';
import angular from 'angular';

export default function(app) {
  app.controller('applicationsCtrl', function($scope, ngTableParams, applicationsFactory, $filter) {
    var vm = this;

    var apps = [{title: "Moroni", clientId: 50, blackListed: "no"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"}, 
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"},
                {title: "train", clientId: 30, blackListed: "Yes"} /*,*/];


$scope.tableParams = new ngTableParams({
                page: 1,
                count: 10
            }, {
                total: apps.length, 
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')(apps, params.orderBy()) : apps;
                    $scope.data = apps.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                    $defer.resolve($scope.data);
                }
            });  
  });
}
```

this is what my partial view looks like

```
<div ng-controller="applicationsCtrl as vm" class="applications container-fluid">
  <div class="applicationsJumbotron jumbotron table-responsive" loading-container="vm.tableParams.settings().$loading">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button" ng-click="vm.registerApplication()">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Register Applications 
    </button>
    <br/>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr class="appTableTh">
          <th>Application Title</th>
          <th>Application ClientId</th>
          <th>Blacklist Status</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="container-fluid">
        <tr ng-repeat="application in $data" ng-class-even="'appTblEvn'" ng-class-odd="'appTblOdd'">
          <td sortable="'title'">
            {{application.title}}
          </td>
          <td sortable="'clientId'">
            {{application.clientId}}
          </td>
          <td sortable="'blackListed'">
            {{application.blackListed}}
          </td>    
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table> 
  </div>
</div>
```

There are no error messages in the console so I am not sure what I am looking for here. Is it an error in my getData() function?

Comment: Can you provide an example of where you call `getData()`, specifically the `params` object you pass in?

Comment: I am actually not specifically calling it anywhere, that's all of the code there is. Where should I be calling it?

Comment: I am not fetching data from the server yet so I just have mockdata so far.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ngtable, but I would recommend putting a `debugger` breakpoint into your `getData()` method to see what's going on in there (or whether it's even called). I probably can't help any more without a plunkr.

Comment: I actually don't have access to all of the code yet so I can't throw it in a plunkr. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I think you need to use the full properties in the `sortable` attribute, e.g.: `sortable="'application.title'"`

Comment: Nope still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the `<thead><thead>` elements and just use the `ng-title` in the `td`, that did it for me.

```
<div ng-controller="applicationsCtrl as vm" class="applications container-fluid">
  <div class="applicationsJumbotron jumbotron table-responsive" loading-container="vm.tableParams.settings().$loading">
    <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="button" ng-click="vm.registerApplication()">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Register Applications 
    </button>
    <br/>
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-condensed">
        <tr ng-repeat="application in $data" ng-class-even="'appTblEvn'" ng-class-odd="'appTblOdd'">
          <td data-title="'Title'" ng-title="'title'" sortable="'title'">
            {{application.title}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{application.clientId}}
          </td>
          <td>
            {{application.blackListed}}
          </td>    
        </tr>
    </table> 
  </div>
</div>
```